# Address Sanitizer thread limit exceeded

Tags: c++, g++, pthreads, address-sanitizer

I am profiling a program compiled with gcc 6.1 with -fsanitize=address option. The program is multi-threaded with clean exits for each thread (with pthread_exit).

Address Sanitizer fails with the message:
==16800==AddressSanitizer: Thread limit (4194304 threads) exceeded. Dying.

The thread count makes no sense (there is no way I am allocating that many threads).  Is there a way I can instrument AddressSanitizer to see where and how the threads are being created?

Comment: Clean exit from thread routine is through return, and not `pthread_exit`.

Comment: @SergeyA: What? That's not true at all. I suspect missing `pthread_join()` or `pthread_detach()`.

Comment: @EOF, of course it is true. pthread_exit() will **not** call destructors of automatic objects created in thread function, so it can't be called 'clean' way of exiting.

Comment: I should note that this is on linux and /proc/pid/status does not show nearly as many threads (the maximum is 32 as expected).